# Disabled account and terminated employee workstation trying to authenticate.

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

A former employee's workstation is still trying to authenticate on the domain. His account is disabled and a GPO disabling cached log-in attempts is in place. This is happening about 1-2 times per hour.

[image: email notification]

Comment: Some script/scheduled task/etc running on it?  Why not just make an image of the workstation using clonezilla, etc. and then wipe and reinstall for the next employee?

Comment: no, nothing running. deactivated for about 2 years. just started getting these starting the 3rd of july

Comment: User and Computer logons are different things. Which are you referring to, the user or the computer?

Comment: I'm referring to computer logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though the account was disabled, it was still set to never expire. I set the account to end and haven't seen an attempt in ~6 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

This is error 4740 and the protocol repeats the workstation name supplied in the login request instead of verifying it.

Turn on NTLM authentication auditing and check 4776 failures in the log "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\NTLM\Operational" to see the real source.

Since the caller computer name is "Workstation" I suspect this is a spoofed request and you will be interested to see what is going on with the actual source of the attempts

Comment: NTLM auditing returned this for the attempt:
Secure Channel name: EX01
User name: username
Domain name: NULL
Workstation name: WORKSTATION
Secure Channel type: 2